# Normalizar tabela para a 2FN

Tags: sql

Estou com uma tabela super mal feita em mãos e necessito normalizar esta até à 2FN. Alguém me pode dar umas dicas? Não estou a conseguir aplicar a teoria nesta tabela. Eis uma amostra dela: (o atributo "cidade" repete-se apesar de nesta amostra não se repetir)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Precisamos entender o problema para orientar melhor. Sem um detalhei sto poderia ser adequado. Claro que tem coisas aparentemente ruins, mas só se soubermos os requisitos.

Comment: **Uma relação encontra-se na segunda forma normal (2FN) se e somente se estiver em primeira forma normal (1FN) e não contém dependências parciais.** Mediante a isso precisa inicialmente perguntar sobre a primeira forma normal e verificar se suas tabelas estão normalizadas.

Comment: Não percebi onde querias chegar, mas isto é uma tabela com eventos realizados em Portugal. Em "designação original" está o nome do evento, e o resto dos atributos acho que se percebe

Comment: Como @Maniero disse acima, precisa melhorar a pergunta e mostrar todas as entidades existentes na database. Além disso seria necessário antes verificar se suas tabelas estão normalizadas na primeira forma normal; ou seja senão existem campos contendo valores compostos, que gerariam outras entidades. Como a segunda forma normal precisa da primeira forma normal (1FN) obrigatoriamente, é necessário que forneça mais detalhes em sua pergunta.

Comment: Um exemplo prático do que estou dizendo é o atributo "Termo especifico" contido em sua tabela, repare que o valores atribuídos são compostos "Cultura e Lazer" se o sistema necessitar pesquisar parte desse valor ou seja procurar apenas por **Cultura** ou apenas por **Lazer** essa tabela não respeitaria a  primeira forma normal (1FN) esse caso depende especificamente das regras do negócios, uma vez que não está na primeira forma normal jamais estará na segunda.

Comment: Mas o valor tem mesmo esse nome, e não se pode decompor o mesmo

Comment: Com todo respeito como dizia um cara que foi meu chefe o seu problema está "gasoso" ...

Comment: @Carrilho Ao meu ver, temos que levar em consideração a definição que o Rafael Salomão deixou, de não estar na 1FN e não conter dependências parciais. Então temos que sua Designação define a duração e a periodicidade; Distrito define cidade; e os termos chave definem os termos correntes que definem os termos específicos. Por definir, digo que estas se tornariam tabelas próprias. Depois passaria para 3NF e retiraria as dependências transitivas. Como todos os dados são atômicos, essa tabela já está na 1FN.